# What is the required value for the Window argument in RenderView

Tags: flutter, dart

I am busy migrating a project to null-safety and am running into an issue with the following code snippet:

```
RenderView(
 child: RenderPositionedBox(
 alignment: Alignment.center,
 child: repaintBoundary,
 ),
 configuration: ViewConfiguration(
 size: logicalSize,
 devicePixelRatio: 1.0,
 ),
 window: null,
)
```

The `window` argument is not nullable and requires a `FlutterView` which is an abstract class, google is not helping me figure out what actually needs to be used there.

Tx

Comment: See *Implementers* section of [`FlutterView` docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView-class.html).

Comment: @Enzo that just errors saying FlutterWindow has no default constructor

Comment: You can see the implementers of `FlutterWindow` and there will be a single one called `SingletonFlutterWindow`. [There](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/SingletonFlutterWindow-class.html), it says that you can get a `FlutterWindow` by calling `WidgetsBinding.instance.window`. You can try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
 window: WidgetsBinding.instance!.window;
```

Was answered by @Enzo, I only give it more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Update: `WidgetsBinding.instance.window` has been deprecated in Flutter 3.10.

The suggestion is to use `View.of(context)` to get a `FlutterView`, now. This is in preparation for multi-window support.